# How to form a matrix of distances between sites in Python?

Tags: python

I have all the data (sites and distances already).

Now I have to form a string matrix to use as an input for another python script.

I have sites and distances as (returned from a query, delimited as here):

```
A|B|5
A|C|3
A|D|9
B|C|7
B|D|2
C|D|6
```

How to create this kind of matrix?

```
  A|B|C|D
A|0|5|3|9
B|5|0|7|2
C|3|7|0|6
D|9|2|6|0
```

This has to be returned as a string from python and I'll have more than 1000 sites, so it should be optimized for such size.

Thanks

Comment: L=[[i for i in range(0,4)]]*4 you can create according to this way

Answer (score 1):

I have no doubt it could be done in a cleaner way (because Python).
I will do some more research later on but I do want you to have something to start with, so here it is.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
 ('A','B',5)
,('A','C',3)
,('A','D',9)
,('B','C',7)
,('B','D',2)
,('C','D',6)
]

data.extend([(y,x,val) for x,y,val in data])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','val'])
df = df.pivot_table(values='val', index='x', columns='y')
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Here is a demo for 1000x1000 (take about 2 seconds)

```
import pandas as pd, itertools as it

data = [(x,y,val) for val,(x,y) in enumerate(it.combinations(range(1000),2))]

data.extend([(y,x,val) for x,y,val in data])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','val'])
df = df.pivot_table(values='val', index='x', columns='y')
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks David, I will try it